# Determining of the intermediate fields of the $12$th cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\zeta$ be a 12th primitive root over $\mathbb Q$. Determine all intermediate field of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q$.

My problem is that this is a task from an old exam where you were not allowed to use some sheets which you prepared at home.

So I would like to know if there are some possibilities in terms of determining the intermediate field **without** knowing the 12th cyclotomic polynomial (I guess nobody have to memorize all of them..)

So I am looking for something like a "trick" or way how to solve this task. Maybe something which I dont know yes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you remember what the Galois group of the $m$th cyclotomic field looks like, and how it acts on the roots of unity? That **is** something you can/should memorize. Knowing the exact 12th cyclotomic polynomial is not very useful here. This is an application of Galois theory.

Comment: Ah yes. The galois group of the mth cyclotomic polynomial is isomorphis to the group $(\mathbb Z_m)^{\times}$, right? So I have to determine the number of the elements in that group. So i have to determine #$\{a\in \mathbb Z\text{ : }gcd(a,m)=1 \text{ and } 0\leq a<m\} $. There are 4 elements in the galois group. Hence its isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. I guess I can take it from here by myself. If I got problems I will ask again, thanks a lot!:)

Comment: Hello. I got still one question. One subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is $<(0,1)>$ but how can I determine the associated fixed field? Its no problem if I would know which element of $S_4$ belongs to $(0,1)$..

Answer (score 3):

The Galois group is $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)^* \cong V_4$, hence there are $3$ proper intermediate fields of degree $2$, which are made up of square roots.

Obviously the fourth and the third root of unity give rise to the intermediate fields $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{3})$. So the third one is given by $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 1):

It’s worth while recognizing what the twelfth roots of unity *are*. You know that the cube roots of unity are, they’re $1$ and $(-1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$. You also know what the fourth roots of unity are, they’re $\pm1$ and $\pm i$. Combine them in an appropriate way and you’ll get the twelfth roots; but looking at the irrationalities I’ve written out, you can see immediately what the intermediate quadratic fields are.

And although you certainly didn’t need the twelfth cyclotomic polynomial, it’s easy to calculate, as $X^4-X^2+1$. You do this by looking first for the sixth polynomial, which is $X^2-X+1$, and noticing that the primitive twelfth roots of unity are the square roots of the primitive sixth roots.